# Error calling DELETE - (403) Insufficient permissions for this file" | Google Drive API

Tags: php, rest, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I have created following code. I have to download files from my Google Drive folder. The folder is shared. After downloading, I have to delete those files from the Google Drive.

I tried -

1. `$file = $service->parents->delete($file_id,$folder_id);` - It doesn't do anything, nor does it give any error.
2. `$file = $service->files->trash($file_id);` - It gives **Error calling DELETE  - (403) Insufficient permissions for this file"** Error.

**My code :**

```
<?php
require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

require_once "google/vendor/autoload.php";

$file_id = '1bJm_cqIRVh5RaVrqVXGRL0CSYwTBlZur';
$folder_id='1gEllj4B9TCnLPe_dnl1ujX4u8smLL-Ky';

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'service_account_email@domain.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'GoogleDriveApi-7cd8056e9eae.p12';


function buildService() {//function for first build up service
global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;

$key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
$auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, array($DRIVE_SCOPE), $key);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
return new Google_DriveService($client);
```

}

```
function printFilesInFolder($service, $folderId) {
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $arrayFile=array();
  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $children = $service->children->listChildren($folderId, $parameters);
      $arrayFile=$children;
      $pageToken = $children->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $arrayFile;
}

try {

    $service = buildService();

    $children=printFilesInFolder($service,$folder_id);

    $myfile = fopen("D:/list.txt", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
    foreach ($children->getItems() as $child) {
        print "\r\nFile Id: " . $child->getId();
        fwrite($myfile, $child->getId());
        fwrite($myfile, "\r\n");  
      }      
    $file = $service->parents->delete($file_id,$folder_id);
    $file = $service->files->trash($file_id);

    fclose($myfile);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred1: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [error](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) indicates that the user doesn't have a write access to the file, and an app is attempting to modify the particular file.

> Suggested action: Report to the user that there is a need to ask for
>   those permissions in order to update the file. You may also want to
>   check user access levels in the metadata retrieved by
>   [**`files.get`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) and use that to change your UI to a read only UI.